# Importing Multiple tables at same hdfs location using sqoop

Tags: db2, sqoop

Is there any way to import multiple tables at a single HDFS location using sqoop.I Have 5 tables in db2 schema(tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5),and one hdfs location /user/hive/db2_tables. I want to store db2 data as below.

```
    /user/hive/db2_tables/tab1
    /user/hive/db2_tables/tab2
    /user/hive/db2_tables/tab3
    /user/hive/db2_tables/tab4
    /user/hive/db2_tables/tab5
```

but after importing first table when I'm giving same target directory in 2nd sqoop command its showing directory already exists.
I'm using below sqoop command.

```
    sqoop import -Dmapreduce.output.basename="tab1" --connect jdbc:db2://xx.x.x.xxx:xxxxx/db2 --query 
    "select * from schemaname.tablename where  \$CONDITIONS " --username username -P --split-by id
     --target-dir /user/hive/db2_tables/ --fields-terminated-by '|'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `warehouse-dir` instead of `target-dir` argument.

With `warehouse-dir` you have to indicate a `HDFS` parent directory for table destination.
For example: `db2_tables`, so first table will go to `/user/hive/db2_tables/tab1`, second table will go to `/user/hive/db2_tables/tab2` and so on.

Your script would be as follow:

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.output.basename="tab1" \
--connect jdbc:db2://xx.x.x.xxx:xxxxx/db2 \
--query "select * from schemaname.tablename where  \$CONDITIONS " \
--username username -P \
--split-by id \
--warehouse-dir /user/hive/db2_tables/ \
--fields-terminated-by '|'
```